# Simple for loop in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have two arrays declared as `fMarksL4[6]` and `marksL4[12]`. I have taken the input from user to all values of `marksL4[]` and want to assign them to `fMarksL4[]` as following. Is there a simple way to do this using a loop?

```
fMarksL4[0] = (marksL4[0] + marksL4[1]) / 2;
fMarksL4[1] = (marksL4[2] + marksL4[3]) / 2;
fMarksL4[2] = (marksL4[4] + marksL4[5]) / 2;
fMarksL4[3] = (marksL4[6] + marksL4[7]) / 2;
fMarksL4[4] = (marksL4[8] + marksL4[9]) / 2;
fMarksL4[5] = (marksL4[10] + marksL4[11]) / 2;
```

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: you should at least do a little research before posting a question. This is too silly a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop should work

```
for(int i=0; i< fMarksL4.length ; i++){
        fMarksL4[i] = (marksL4[2 * i] + marksL4[2 * i + 1])/2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, notice that you are accessing the `marksL4` at double (and double plus one) the current `fMarksL4` index. So you could loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < fMarksL4.length; i++) {
    int j = i * 2;
    fMarksL4[i] = (marksL4[j] + marksL4[j + 1]) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this using loops

```
void solve(){
int j=0;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
  fMarksL4[i] = (marksL4[j] + marksL4[j+1])/2
  j=j+2;
}

}
```